# Offline_enabled crx property not supported in Chrome 14-

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to upgrade my Chrome app to support `offline_enabled` flag in CRX manifest. However, when I test it with Chrome 14, it gives me the following error message and it stop downloading the crx.

"Package is invalid. Details: Hosted Apps Cannot use the extension feature 'offline_enabled'"

Any idea how to resolve this problem for Chrome version lower than 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Chrome bug.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98537